# Update cell value in Table - repeater using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have repeater and it gets a column value from modalpopup. I need to set that on 3rd from last and 2nd cell anchor tag. Below is my code snippet.
It is working on IE, but not in Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

```
{   
  var repeater = $("#pubRepeater");
  var numberofrows = repeater.find('tr').length;
  var lastcell = repeater.find('tr')[numberofrows - 3];
  lastcell.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].innerText = 'New Value';
}
```

Comment: Why not using StackOveflow's code formatting to make your question more readable? In any line you want to write code, simply add 4 space characters at the beginning.

Comment: New to this site and Thanks for making this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that while you're using jQuery, you're not using at all the way. The .innerText property is specific to IE, so why not use the method jQuery provides?

```
$('td a', lastcell).text('New Value');
```

If the td is the last td in the row, then:

```
$('td:last a', lastcell).text('New Value');
```

If you are trying to update the actual HTML rather than the text, then use .html instead of .text

The second arguement in the $() selector is the scope in which it should look for the elements in the first arguement. Since you've already found the last row, it's far more efficient to tell jQuery to look for the 'td:last a' elements only in that row.

Also, by using the 'td:last a' instead of childNode[0].childNode[1], you make your code much more extensible. Now, if you add more columns or additional elements to the last column, you won't have to go and change your childNode indexes to match.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
       lastcell.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].html('New Value');

                          or

       lastcell.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].text('New Value')
```

Hope this helps..